# Best way to perform query to get total count - SQLAlchemy, PostgreSQL and FastAPI

Tags: postgresql, performance, sqlalchemy, count, fastapi

I already read all related questions and their answers. Still facing same issue.

Database: PostgreSQL
Framework: FastAPI (Python)
ORM: SQLAlchemy

Query

```
posts_count = db.query(Posts.postId).filter(Posts.postOwner == user_id, Posts.postStatus == True).count()
```

I use above query to get count with conditions and on heavy load it takes time. I search and optimize the query as

```
posts_count = db.query(func.count(Posts.postId)).filter(Posts.postOwner == user_id, Posts.postStatus == True).scalar()
```

Query Analysis

```
Aggregate  (cost=16937.27..16937.28 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts  (cost=606.88..16832.52 rows=41900 width=16)
        Recheck Cond: ?
        Filter: ?
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "ix_posts_postOwner"  (cost=0.00..596.41 rows=43731 width=0)
              Index Cond: ?
```

Still query took a lot of time. Anyone can help? Appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered an index on both postOwner and postStatus? Returning the count in that case should generally only be a single index lookup in that case (you might need a different index type); I also assume that `postId` is the primary key of your table.

Comment: You mean adding composite indexing on postOwner and postStatus, let me try and get back with results.

Answer (score -1):

try using indexing,

CREATE INDEX *index_name*
ON *table_name*(*colum*);

keep in mind by default the index is a Btree and looking at your code you wont need to use any other type of index.

if you need more documentation on creating an index refer to this - https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-create-index/